# Cannot add Storage Account in Diagnostic Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I have just created a free Azure account and had a web app service created. Then I want to enable Diagnostic settings for "Archive to a storage account", but the problem is that it doesn't show any my storage account. I did create a dedicating storage account for it. Could you please have a look on the picture for more detail.
Please note I can enable this Diagnostic setting in Virtual Machine instance, just not for web app service.

Thanks

[Storage Account didn't show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ4qD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to double check that your storage account is:

- In the same region
- Not premium storage
- Not a BlockBlob only storage account

Comment: thank you so much Sam Cogan! the problem is that my storage account is not in the same region with Web App.